# Ansible - starting a task after cpu load is below 2.0

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to create a playbook where I want to perform a simple debug task after cpu load is below 2.0.

I have this so far in `cpu-load.yml`:

```yaml
---
- name: Check CPU load and wait
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  
  tasks:
    - name: Check cpu load
      shell: uptime | awk -F 'load average:' '{print $2}' | awk -F ', ' '{print $1}'
      register: cpu_load
      
    - name: Wait until cpu load is bellow 2.0
      wait_for:
        timeout: 300
        delay: 10
        shell: Do something here
        msg: "cpu load is bellow 2.0"
      
    - name: Continue jobs
      debug:
        msg: "CPU load is bellow 2.0. Continue!!!"
```

Now I am not sure how to make the task wait for the cpu load to go bellow 2.0. Can you guys help?

Comment: Why are you doing this? And why are you solving this w ansible, instead of e.g. Bash or Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put an [`until` loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met) around your "check cpu load" task:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Check cpu load
      shell: uptime | awk -F 'load average:' '{print $2}' | awk -F ', ' '{print $1}'
      register: cpu_load
      until: cpu_load.stdout|float < 2.0
      retries: 300
      delay: 1

    - name: Some other task
      debug:
        msg: hello world
```

This will wait up to five minutes (300 retries with a 1-second delay) for the load average to drop below 2.0.

---

There are probably better ways to get the current 1-minute CPU load; reading from `/proc/loadavg` may be easiest:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Check cpu load
      command: cat /proc/loadavg
      register: cpu_load
      until: cpu_load.stdout.split()|first|float < 2.0
      retries: 300
      delay: 1

    - name: Some other task
      debug:
        msg: hello world
```

Answer (score 2):

Building up on [@larsks answer](/a/76382917/9401096) and going further regarding the sentence

> There are probably better ways to get the current 1-minute CPU load

There's actually a fact containing this information, at least on linux, e.g.

```
$ ansible localhost -m setup -a gather_subset='!all,!min,loadavg'
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_loadavg": {
            "15m": 0.669921875,
            "1m": 0.48974609375,
            "5m": 0.4501953125
        },
        "gather_subset": [
            "!all",
            "!min",
            "loadavg"
        ],
        "module_setup": true
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

---

Notes:

1. `gather_subset='!all,!min,loadavg'` ensures that stricly only the needed facts are gathered (and refreshed in the below playbook). For more information, see the [option documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#parameter-gather_subset)
2. the `loadavg` subset is not documented at time I write these lines but is listed in the allowed options from the module error message in my ansible 2.14.6 / 2.15.0 versions (see below)

---

Knowing this and applying the same recipe as in @larsk's answer, the check can be implemented as:

```yaml
---
- name: Demo play to check load and continue
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Check load before next tasks
      ansible.builtin.setup:
        gather_subset:
          - '!all'
          - '!min'
          - 'loadavg'
      retries: 30
      delay: 5
      until: ansible_loadavg['1m'] < 2.00

    - name: Now do something on a cooled down system
      debug:
        msg: I'm doing something without pressure
```

---

Regarding the undocumented subset for the `setup` module, here is a quick and dirty solution to list all accepted subsets in your version of the module:

```
$ ansible localhost -m setup -a gather_subset='toto'
localhost | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Bad subset 'toto' given to Ansible. gather_subset options allowed: all, all_ipv4_addresses, all_ipv6_addresses, apparmor, architecture, caps, chroot, cmdline, date_time, default_ipv4, default_ipv6, devices, distribution, distribution_major_version, distribution_release, distribution_version, dns, effective_group_ids, effective_user_id, env, facter, fibre_channel_wwn, fips, hardware, interfaces, is_chroot, iscsi, kernel, kernel_version, loadavg, local, lsb, machine, machine_id, mounts, network, nvme, ohai, os_family, pkg_mgr, platform, processor, processor_cores, processor_count, python, python_version, real_user_id, selinux, service_mgr, ssh_host_key_dsa_public, ssh_host_key_ecdsa_public, ssh_host_key_ed25519_public, ssh_host_key_rsa_public, ssh_host_pub_keys, ssh_pub_keys, system, system_capabilities, system_capabilities_enforced, user, user_dir, user_gecos, user_gid, user_id, user_shell, user_uid, virtual, virtualization_role, virtualization_tech_guest, virtualization_tech_host, virtualization_type"
}
```